# Socket.IO Real time Chat

Tags: socket.io

Im trying to get a specified room using socket.io but its giving error 'room undefined'. Below is my code. Can anybody please help? or explain whats the problem

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

socket.on('join', ({name, room}, callback ) => {
    console.log(name, room);
    const {error, user} = addUser({id: socket.id, name, room});
    if(error) return callback(error);

    //greeting message for user when joins room
    socket.emit('message', {user: 'admin', text: `${user.name}, welcome to the room ${user.room}`});
    //greet message to everyone in room that user has joined
    socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message', {user: 'admin', text : `${user.name} has joined.`});

    socket.join(user.room);//puts user in room
    callback();

});
socket.on('sendMessage', (message, callback) => {

    const user = getUser(socket.id);// get user by id 

    io.to(user.room).emit('message', {user: user.name, text: message});
    callback();
});


socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User have left!!');
})
```

});

Comment: Hi, It's probably where you emit 'join' event you wont send an object like `{ name: 'name', room: 'room' }`. So it won't destruct room out. what is the output of console.log(name, room); ?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is from the client side. The sever is ok. The front-end is not sending room the user entered. check it out.